# If Γ,A∧B⊢Δ is an axiom, then also Γ,A,B⊢Δ is an axiom

Tags: logic, axioms, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

**Context**

I am studying sequent calculus, and I am trying to understand the proof that the rule L∧ introducing

"$\land $" on the left:
${\displaystyle \quad {\cfrac {\Gamma ,A,B\vdash \Delta }{\Gamma ,A\land B\vdash \Delta }}}$

is invertible, where invertible means that as soon as I have a derivation of height $n$ of the conclusion, I also have a derivation of the same height of the premise.
Here I am considering sequents for classical logic, and I define an axiom as a sequent $\Gamma \vdash \Delta $ , such that $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are finite multisets sharing at least one formula.
The proof is by induction on the height of the derivation, and starts with the case $n=0$.

**Problem:**

The proof is easy and follows inductively from the fact that, if

**(1)**$\displaystyle \quad \Gamma ,A\land B\vdash \Delta$ is an axiom,

then also **(2)** $\displaystyle \quad \Gamma ,A,B\vdash \Delta$ is an axiom.

My reasoning is that it can be the case that $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ don't share any formula, and $A \land B$ is in $\Delta$, so that **(1)** is an axiom, but in this case I don't understand how to prove rigorously why **(2)** should be.

Thanks for reading

Comment: It is not clear what "invertible" means.

Comment: I edited. Thanks

Comment: Then how on earth can it be true? ( A ∧ B ) ∧ C ⊢ ( A ∧ B ) ∧ C in at most one step, but A,B,C ⊢ ( A ∧ B ) ∧ C in at least two steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is because you work in sequent calculus, which only admits axioms in form $\Gamma\vdash\Delta$, where $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ share an **atomic** formula. I would recommend a book by Troelstra and Schwichteberg: *Basic proof theory*. Here this system is called $\mathrm{G}3$, see Definition 3.5.1.

Comment: That is what I thought too. Thank you very much for the answer and for the reference. The one I am reading wasn't clear about that point.